# Understanding Excel MATCH function - Numeric array not necessarily sorted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I come across this or similar Excel MATCH formula, in a few answers posted on Superuser.

```
=MATCH(99^99,B:B,1)
```

This returns the position of the last cell in column B that has numeric data in it (Assuming there is no entry greater than 99^99 in column B)

Basically it is expected to return the  largest value that is less than or equal to  the Lookup Value. However I am having difficulty understanding how this formula really works!  It is expected that when Match_Type (Last parameter) is 1, the array should be sorted in ascending order for this function to work.

So it’s working even if the array is not sorted in ascending order. Or is that the  trick? Instead of returning error when array is unsorted, does it  simply treat the last element as the only element for comparison?  Thanks.

Comment: You're supposed to use `MATCH(..,..,1)` only on arrays sorted in ascending order. Otherwise you shouldn't have any expectations on the output.

Comment: You're taking advantage of Excel's gullibility to get what you want.  You give Excel a non-existent large value as a target and tell Excel the data is sorted.  Excel assumes that if it can't find a match (which it never will), the last value will be the closest, so it returns the last value.  You're not interested in the actual values, you just want the last one.  So telling Excel a white lie about the data being sorted lets it return what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this works because excel must be using Binary Search internally and it assumes that the list is sorted and just goes on performing binary search till it finds the last value.